# Getting a double major, with one subject's GPA being much higher than the other. How should I deal with it?

Tags: masters, computer-science, physics, gpa

I'm double majoring in physics and computer science. Due to extremely high demand, the CS department at my university expects many unreasonable demands from the student body (not the tough but fair type of demands, the sloppy "we made a mistake and you take responsibly" type of demands). The physics department I find very fair and very compassionate.

My average in the physics courses is about 97 (out of 100), and will hopefully stay in the ~95 range throughout my studies. My CS average seems like it may go as low as 80-85.

My question is: applying for a master's degree specifically in physics, would the lower CS average be a disadvantage for me, or would they focus on my average in physics?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it has a common sense answer: double major students with OP's grades have little to worry about.

Comment: Isn't it very dependent on the situation? What if I want to get into a top school for my master's? Also, I think this should remain open for people with lower grades anyways. This isn't relevant merely to people with a high GPA.

Comment: Buffy offered you a reasonable answer. Ain't much more anyone can add.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that this is the US, you are probably ok, but admissions to graduate programs is done by individuals so no one can predict exactly.

Generally speaking, though, the upper level grades (especially) in the field in which you want to study are the most important consideration. The overall GPA has importance in the weeding operation, but if you survive the initial cut, it will most likely be your physics courses and grades that will carry higher weight.

And, I suggest that you don't complain in an interview about the unfairness of the CS department. Such things can reflect badly on you rather than the target. Good luck.

Comment: What do "upper level grades" mean? English is not my native language.
Also, your phrasing makes it seem like there is some weight to the problem at hand ("it will most likely", "carry a higher weight"..). Would that be correct?

Comment: Upper level means the advanced courses, usually taken in the later years. Not (in CS) fundamental programming and data-structures courses, for example. Higher weight means more important in the considerations.

Comment: So it will be somewhat of a disadvantage? Sorry for looking for a yes-or-no type answer, but in general, do you see it as a considerable disadvantage?

Comment: Don't try to parse it too finely. People are involved and they have their own standards. But probably not a big issue if your physics grades are good in advanced courses.

Comment: In OP's other [question](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/200206/43873) about fairness, they clarified it is Israel.

Comment: I did. I might not pursue my master's in Israel though, and I see no relevance in that.

Comment: And, regardless of your grades, any professor in any graduate school can reject you on grounds of interpersonal incompatibility, incongruous perspectives, disagreeable personality, excess individualism/shyness/sneakiness/ambitiousness/ . . .